# About Graphics Magick for node Error

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I run nodejs in windows and install gm with npm.

`var readStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/../temp/a.jpg');
gm(readStream, 'a.jpg').write(__dirname + '/../temp/b.png', function (err) {if (err) console.log(err);});`

Then I got the msg:

`{ [Error: Command failed: CreateProcessW: ϵͳ�Ҳ���ָ�����ļ���] code: 127, signal: null }`

Does gm support the windows or how could I deal with?

Answer (score 6):

Putting the GraphicsMagick installation directory in the PATH environment variable solved the problem for me.

Comment: Could you please explain how to do this? I get the above error although my system variable 'Path' already includes: c:\program files\graphicsmagick-1.3.18-q8;

Comment: Nevermind, seems I'm an idiot. Just needed to restart for the path variable to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first install GraphicsMagick (http://www.graphicsmagick.org/). Then:

```
npm install gm
```